# Will HashMap#put/remove suffer any ConcurrentModificationException if used from multiple threads

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap

In Test.java

```
public static Map<String, Integer> testMap=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

In TestServlet.java

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
  Test.testMap.put("cool", 1);
}
```

In TestServlet2.java

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
  Test.testMap.remove("cool");
}
```

In `test.html`, there is a function to call TestServlet every 3 secs

```
mTimer = setTimeout('getTest();',3000); //call TestServlet in 3 seconds
```

In `test2.html`, there is a function to call TestServlet2 every 2 secs

```
mTimer = setTimeout('getTest2();',2000); //call TestServlet in 2 seconds
```

Now, I run `test.html` & `test2.html` at the same time & no problem occur.

Of course, if I replace `public static Map<String, Integer> testMap=new HashMap<String, Integer>();` with `public static List<String> testList=new ArrayList<String>();`, then I got `ConcurrentModificationException`

My question is that? Can `HashMap` suffer any `ConcurrentModificationException` or be Thread-safe?

I have not tried to modify the value of each key of the `Map` so I don't know what is going on.

Comment: You don't get a CME simply by putting and removing at the same time. You get a CME when you are iterating the map and something modifies the underlying collection.

Comment: Remember that not all internal corruption throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`, you may corrupt the map without throwing anything, if you then access the corrupted value, you may get a totaly out of order exception

Comment: try accessing key set using `testMap.keySet ( )`. Iterate over this set and remove a key. Lets see what you get .

Comment: You seem to think that ConcurrentModificationException is about thread safety. It isn't.

Comment: @Raedwald, yes, I just want to have a consistent result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashMap`s are not thread safe and should be used wisely. If you want to use key value pairs type of data structure `ConcurrentHashMap` is recommended in multithreaded environment.

Comment: "**ConcurrentHashMap** doesn’t throw a **ConcurrentModificationException** if one thread tries to modify it while another is iterating over it."??--> will that cause any problem?

Comment: No It won't! Concurrent hashmap is designed to work in such scenarios

Comment: http://crunchify.com/hashmap-vs-concurrenthashmap-vs-synchronizedmap-how-a-hashmap-can-be-synchronized-in-java/

Comment: What about **Collections.synchonizedMap(new HashMap<String, Integer>());**

Comment: This is slow in performance when multiple reads writes happen on it. While in case of Concurrent hashmap only writes are exclusive on a particular segment and not on the whole map

Comment: Ok, let say if I use "**ConcurrentHashMap**" & I have 2 threads running at the same time. Thread1 modifies the Map & Thread2 reads it. So Thread2 will returns the list that does not include the latest modification, right? But if I use synchronizedMap then I can see the latest data right?

Comment: Right. But in concurrent hashmap, its not necessary that you wont see the changes. It may or may not be present at that point of time.

Comment: But why there is no "ConcurrentList"? Will   CopyOnWriteArrayList  play the similar role to ConcurrentMap? & Why Collections.synchronizedList got problem when you remove item while other threads are iritating it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can see from the source code that the iterator throws such an exception:

```
808         final Entry<K,V> nextEntry() {
809             if (modCount != expectedModCount)
810                 throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
```

And `modCount` is incremented in the `put` method and other places.

Note that this is not necessarily restricted to the issue of thread-safety. A same-thread sequence of operations could cause the exception to be thrown if a `put` operation was done while between two iterator operations.